# get_post_meta returning broken path in image src

Tags: images, post-meta

I am using a custom field to store the path to an image and then using `get_post_meta()` to insert that path into an `<img>`

Here is my code:
`<img src"<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slide_one_image', true ); ?>" />`

For some reason this is outputting `<img src"http: wp_project2 wp-content uploads 2016 01 slider1a.jpg">` which is the correct path but without the `/`'s

When I include  outside of the image tag it returns the appropriate path, i.e. `http://wp_project2/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/slider1a.jpg`

I can't figure out why it is broken when used within the image tag. I have used this exact snippet (grabbing a different custom field value) elsewhere in the site and it has worked perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left out the `=` in `<img src="...`

So the code should look like `<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slide_one_image', true ); ?>" />`

Thanks